# ActionBarSherlock Tabs+Fragments+MapView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, actionbarsherlock-map

Actually I have 2 Fragments, one is Menu and other is Content Fragment. Now I need to add Google Map to the Content Fragment. I have added Google Maps Plugin for ABS. But how to use it in a Fragment. I can

```
public class MapActivity extends SherlockMapActivity
```

but how to make it done in a `Fragment`

like: `public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment`

Actually I want to use two tabs in a fragment (say Fragment B) and show some textview in one tab and mapview in other fragment. I have FragmentActivy (Home) and it has two fragments A and B. A is sliding menu and B is content menu.

Is is possible to show two tabs in a fragment and use two different layouts in two tabs ?

I cannot `extends SherlockMapActivity` as I need to use it in a `Fragment` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapViews can not be ran as part of a fragment layout. There's no library that will give you that, as long as i know.

Though, there's a hack that will allow you to put a MapView in a fragment, but it's a little bit more elaborated.

You can take a look to it here

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment/

Comment: great tutorial. It worked. But I am now losing its contents when choosing other fragments via Sliding Menu. How to avoid that ? :(

Comment: That's really depends on your sliding menu implementation.

Comment: Not completely sure what that library or your code does, but i think it's a little out of this question topic. Most likely you are loosing any fragment content, not just the MapView.  I would try opening a new question with all the code and relevant information in it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as explained [here](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment/)?

Comment: Actually I have done it using some other example. I dont remember the link exactly. I will post the code soon. Anyways, new version of google map api support fragments!

Comment: Yea I was about to change my answer to mention that, but I'm yet to get it working! :D